# yarn start doesn't open react app on chrome but no errors are thrown?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, react-scripts

I have a simple react app that I started recently just to study a few things and suddenly, when I try to run it with:

```
yarn start
```

it does not throws any error, just stays like this:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ..\package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
```

and nothing happens, what should i do?

PS: my complete package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "prototype",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "framer-motion": "^7.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "start": "^5.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.21.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of the package.json to the question?

Comment: Just did it, it's now on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error message the path of the package.json file is in the warning:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ..\package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
```

That double dots `..\` saying that the package.json file is one folder up from where you are running the `yarn start` command. It could be OUTSIDE the project folder you're working on.

So if you go one directory up you will find another package.json file. Either add `"license"` field into that package.json file or simply delete the file if you do not need it.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Indeed there were another package.json outside of my project folder that were causing some conflict, I deleted it and now no warnings are shown. But, I still run yarn start and it does not open my app, any other ideas?

Comment: What is the error message that you get when you run `yarn start` command?

Comment: No error messages, just 'yarn run v1.22.19' and 'react-scripts start' in the next line.

Comment: That's weird.  what happens when you visit http://localhost:3000/. 

Remove node_modules directory with `rm -rf node_modules` and then run `yarn install` command from the root of the project folder.

Comment: Did not work. What i think it's may happening is that yarn start is not going for the package.json on my current project folder. I had another app that were running before and now that i deleted the package.json that were outside, it is not working too. Is there something I could do to make it run on my current folder only?

Comment: Do you really want this current project nested inside a different project? why not move this project without nesting it inside a different project.

Comment: They are outside and different, it's not nested inside. They were inside my users folder on windows, so I don't know if there's a problem, should they be more isolated then?

Comment: When I read your previous comments I felt that the current project is nested inside the other project. Based on what you are saying now both the projects are isolated and different. You don't have to move the projects.

But its weird that you do not get any error message when you run the `yarn start` command. 

I would  run `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` and then run `yarn install` command from the root of the project folder.

Comment: I did all that + restarted my pc and now they are all back, working! thanks for your time & comprehension.